# Display a div when hovering on image map area

Tags: jquery

Im hoping  someone  can  help  with  a bit of jquery that can display a hidden series of divs when an area rectangle on an image  map  is hovered over.

Here's  what ive  got in brief there are  about 15  hot spots. I'm thinking  i  could  use jquery  to  remove the  .hide class  from the  div with the  same id as the  item name in the image map.  Is this  the  right  approach?

```
<map name="services" >
<area shape="rect" coords="288, 152, 471, 191" href="#" item="brand"      alt="brand assesment" />
<area shape="rect" coords="210, 227, 358, 271" href="#" alt="focus groups" item="focus" />
</map>

<div  id="brand" class="hide">
brand text
</div>

<div  id="focus" class="hide">
focus stuff
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add javascript code that affects that element and identify that element with an id, for example (with *element-id* for first area element):

```
    $( "#element-id" )
      .mouseover(function() {
        $("#brand").show();
      })
      .mouseout(function() {
        $("#brand").hide();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not clear enough, I assume that you're trying finding `div` with `id` equals the `area`'s attribute `item` which is being hovered.

```
$('area').mouseover(function(){
    $('#' +$(this).attr('item')).removeClass('hide');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#' +$(this).attr('item')).addClass('hide');
})
```

Comment: Thanks  so much  for  sharing  this-  this seems  exactly  what i want  but im not able  to  see it  remove  the  .hide class.  This is in a wordpress site  so i beleive  I  have  to  use  jQuery() instead of  the  $() notation but  trouble shooting it is beyond my skills beyond  that. I made  the page  public at https://1623studios.org/services/  If you  had  a  second  to look at it id certainly be  appreciative.  The only item that has  a  corresponding  div  right now is  Brand Assesment

Comment: The same code paste on console works. The only problem I saw was when I mouseover the area showing `#brand` then mouseleave will be triggered since the mouse is entered `#brand` element.

Comment: Here's the solution of it. Add a class to `#brand` and `$('.CLASS_YOU_ADDED').mouseover(function(){
    $('this').removeClass('hide');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('this').addClass('hide');
})`

Comment: Thank you  so much  for working on this  with me- However  im still not  able  to  get  the  hidden  div(s) to  display.  The  changes you  outlined  are in place  at  the  same url.  Could you  take  another look, Possibly.  Thanks  ever  so much